# Can not get my DataGridTemplateColumn to sort alphabetically

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, xaml

In my WPF aplication I want to be able to sort [some] of my columns. For the most part all my columns that are **DataGridTextColumn** sort alphabetically but the columns I'm having an issue with sorting them alphabetically are two that are: **DataGridTemplateColumn**. Here is how I have my **DataGrid** set up:

```
<DataGrid Name="FooDataGrid"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          CanUserResizeRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <!--Space for declaring DataGridTextColumn here-->
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Foo Bar" 
                              IsReadOnly="False" 
                              SortMemberPath="FooBar" 
                              CanUserSort="True" 
                              SortDirection="Ascending">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding FooBar, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="False"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is my code behind of how I am populating the data:

```
private void InitFooDataGrid() //Gets called in the constructor
{
    FooDataGrid.Items.Clear();
    
    ObservableCollection<Foo> myFooList = GetFooList();

    foreach(Foo foo in ObservableCollection)
    {
        FooDataGrid.Items.Add(foo);
    }
}
```

The end result gets me what I expected, being able to click on the column header and see my rows get sorted. But I noticed something:

[image]

No matter what **SortingDirection** I set it to: *Ascending* or *Descending* it sorts my rows like that. I would like it to where it displays my rows *A->Z* and not *Z->A*

What am I missing? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Any difference if you remove sortdirection?

Comment: How are you populating the grid with data?

Comment: @Keithernet via the code behind (Foo.xaml.cs)

Comment: @Andy no change

Comment: Please post your code-behind and show how you're loading the data. That might be the issue, but we can't tell without seeing that code.

Comment: @Keithernet see my updated content

Comment: Why aren't you setting itemssource to your observablecollection? It seems pointless at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the items are sorted at all. When you take a close look: **Al**len comes before **Av**ery although you expect the items to be in descending order from z to a. "A**v**" therefore must come before "A**l**".

Column sorting is only triggered by the user. He needs to explicitly click the column header. The `DataGrid` then handles the `Button.Click` event to initiate the sorting.

If you want to (pre-)sort the table, you must use the `ICollectionView` of the source collection:

```
private void InitFooDataGrid() //Gets called in the constructor
{    
  ObservableCollection<Foo> myFooList = GetFooList();
  FooDataGrid.ItemsSource = myFooList;

  // Sort by the property 'FooBar' in ascending order
  CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myFooList)
    .SortDescriptions.Add(
      new SortDescription(nameof(Foo.FooBar), ListSortDirection.Ascending));

  // Alternatively use ItemsControl.Items if you have direct access.
  // ItemsControl.Items also returns a ICollectionView of the source collection
  FooDataGrid.Items 
    .SortDescriptions.Add(
      new SortDescription(nameof(Foo.FooBar), ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```